# openssl - can not compute hash of many files

Tags: c++, c, openssl, codeblocks

I code a function to find all of files in my system then put their path into hash function ( a small function). My program works corrently for many first files (~4000 files). After that, the hash function which I code can not compute hash from files.

I code in Code::block 17.12. Using SHA from openssl library.

Hash function:

```
int hashcompute(TCHAR *fpath, char *rs)   {
    unsigned char data[1024*8] = {0};
    size_t length, bytes;
    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
    FILE *fp;

    SHA_CTX context;
    if(!SHA1_Init(&context))
        return 0;

    fp = fopen(fpath, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) return 0;

    while( (bytes = fread(data, 1, 1024*8, fp)))     {
        length = sizeof(data);
        if(!SHA1_Update(&context, (unsigned char*)data, bytes))    return 0;
    }

    if(!SHA1_Final(hash, &context))
        return 0;
    close(fp);
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
//        printf("%02x", hash[i]);
        snprintf((char*)&rs[i*2], length-1, "%02x", hash[i]);
    }
    if (hash == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Some output:

```
Hash: b6d437b942194b19f45015d22d5bc4ab98058038
Result:
Hash: 45031c9a127520c68fb9bf3d19b680525126ab5e
Result:
Hash: 07aea0a3345938068b6e6e91f18edf7a6947a2b9
Result:
Hash: 2e6c38958917fb86f09026d41337c7460efbe5f5
Result:
Hash: fae05ccc1af5711590b68344822febd90049c958
Result:
Hash: 5bf7594ebe9d3b75a790f30046995502b3e5b2b7
Result:
Hash:
Result:
Hash:
Result:
Hash:
Result:
Hash:
Result:
Hash:
```

Comment: Why can't you? Perhaps there is some type of memory leak?

Comment: You probably need to debug to find out yourself.

Comment: @drescherjm I think the reason is lacking of memory. Can I free memory after each hasing?

Comment: I am not sure that the problem is caused by the code that is shown.

Comment: ***I think the reason is lacking of memory*** You should verify this with an OS utility. In windows I would look at the `taskmanager` in linux `top` would work but there are many other ways.

Comment: @drescherjm I verified, however, It was only take ~9MB in total :(

Comment: I define *buf[8*1024] in order that I think it have no problems. Right?

Comment: That is nothing. So running out of memory is not the issue.

Comment: Maybe the file is not opened. I would verify that you are not returning in `if (fp == NULL) return 0;`

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm. I fixed my problem. I should use `fclose()` instead of `close()`